# New security patch SUPEE-6482

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, ce-1.9.1.1

Just wanted to make sure!

I am running CE 1.9.1.1 and my latest update was PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43. Was this the latest security patch for 1.9.1.1?

Is the new security patch SUPEE-6482, only for Magento Community Edition 1.9.2.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Was this the latest security patch for 1.9.1.1?**

Yes, you can use it for 1.9.1.1

**Is the new security patch SUPEE-6482, only for Magento Community Edition 1.9.2.1**

- Magento 1.9.2.1 includes patch SUPEE-6482 in its code.
- SUPEE-6482 is for all versions of Magento CE from 1.4 to 1.9.2.0

[image]

Comment: When I received the email notification of the availability of the new security patch, the link for SUPEE-6482 was not listed on [the download area](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download).  Now it's there. I will try to patch it now.Thank you.

Comment: Patch SUPEE-6482 applied successfully to 1.9.1.1.

Comment: and this is How to install SUPEE-6482 without SSH : http://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6482-without-ssh/

Answer (score 2):

Here are two resources to verify patch requirements:

- [Handy matrix of versions/patches made by wearejh.com](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTbU9Bq130zrrsJwLIB9d8qnGfYZnkm4jBlfNaBF19M/edit#gid=192164130)
- [Check successful patch installation at magereport.com](https://www.magereport.com) (disclaimer: made my me)

Comment: magereport.com reports Security patch 5344 as "unknown"!  Even though a Magento shop is running 1.9.1.1?  Based on matrix, 1.9.1.1 does NOT need patch 5344.  What does that "unknown" means?

Comment: It cannot detect 5344 once 5994 is installed. As patches need to be applied in order, this is usually not a problem. So "unknown" means, you have likely installed it, but we cannot prove it.

Comment: But knowing the fact that it is a fresh install of 1.9.1.1, it should mean it is already installed. Correct?

Comment: yes, 99% sure! Sometimes other code or caching systems prevent successful patch application.

Answer (score 0):

SUPEE-6482 should be installed on "All Magento CE prior to 1.9.2.1" -

You can check the release notes [here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html), which outline what the patch fixes and which versions are affected.

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html

Comment: Also,  when you get the notification for a patch, click "Go to notifications", then click "Read Details" for the patch in question. This will take you to https://www.magentocommerce.com/download, where you can scroll down to the patch and click the "release notes" link to get the details. That's a good habit to have, as they explain things in detail for all patches.